# How to stop JOptionPane from disabling root frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, joptionpane, modality

*How do I show a JOptionPane without disabling any currently open frames?*

I have a JFrame with a Start and Stop button. At any point, I want the user to be able to press the 'Stop' button on the main frame, to stop a secondary Thread (which was started by the Start button).

However the second running Thread sometimes opens a JOptionPane. When it does so, the main frame is disabled, and the user can't press the stop button.

(And when it opens multiple of these JOptionPanes in a row, it becomes immensely frustrating trying to stop it).

I've tried

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It's Broken Mate");
```

With no success. I also tried passing it a JFrame to disable:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Still No Go");
```

That failed too. I even tried

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "CMON Please");
```

And even furthermore,

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);
JOptionPane.setRootFrame(frame);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "I'm getting angry now.");
```

And STILL. Nothing. Does not work. It opens up a message box, and everything is disabled. I have to dismiss the JOptionPane before anything becomes enabled again...

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOptionPane`s are [modal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html), so you can't do this directly.

> All dialogs are modal. Each showXxxDialog method blocks the caller until the user's interaction is complete.

You'll have to use a `JDialog` or similar.

```
    JOptionPane p = new JOptionPane("I'm getting happy now.");
    JDialog k = p.createDialog(":-)");
    k.setModal(false); // Makes the dialog not modal
    k.setVisible(true);
```